# Plain vanilla Hadoop installation vs Hadoop installation using Ambari

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I recently downloaded hadoop distribution from Apache and got it up and running quite fast; download the hadoop tar ball, untar it at a location and some configuration setting. The thing here is that I am able to see the various configuration files like: yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml etc; and I know the hadoop home location.

Next, I installed hadoop  (HDP) Using Ambari.

Here comes the confusion part. It seems Ambarin installs the hdp in /usr/hdp; however the directory structure in plain vanilla hadoop vs Ambari is totally different.  I am not able to locate the configuration files e.g. yarn-site.xml etc.

So can anyone help me demystify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the configuration changes must be done via the **Ambari UI**. There is no use for the configuration files since Ambari persists the configurations in Ambari Database.

If you still need them, they are under `/etc/hadoop/conf/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. So Ambari stores all the configurations in DB? If this is the case, then how Hadoop binaries get these configuration details? Have hdp customised code to read the configurations from DB instead of files? Pls explain a bit more. Thx again for your help and time.

Comment: On start of hadoop daemons, ambari passes them as runtime configurations.

Comment: But this won't be the default behaviour of plain vanilla Hadoop; so is this behaviour created by the customised distribution?

Comment: The startup scripts used in vanilla installation also does pass the conf directory as a runtime parameter. But in the case of ambari, also cloudera manager,they generate these configurations from the data persisted in its db and pass it to the nodes on startup. The difference would be the location of configs is not static as in vanilla.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Hadoop expert friend :)

Comment: Of course :) already saw that! Thanks a ton; your answers really help clear the doubts.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that configuration changes must be made via Ambari UI and that those configurations are stored in a database.

Why is it necessary to change these configuration properties in Ambari UI and not directly on disk?

Every time a service is restarted and it has a stale configuration the ambari-agent is responsible for writing the latest configuration to disk. They are written to `/etc/<service-name>/conf`. If you were to make changes directly to the configuration files on disk they would get overwritten by the aforementioned process.

However the configuration files found on disk **DO** still have a use...

The configuration files (on disk) are used by the various hadoop daemons when they're started/running.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the benefit of using Ambari UI in Cluster Hadoop deployment. It will give you central management point.

For example:

**10 pcs Hadoop cluster setup.**

Plain vanilla Hadoop:

- If you change any configuration you must be changed in 10 pcs

Ambari UI :

- Due to configuration store in db. you just change in management portal all changes effect reflected on all node by single point change.